# Bibliography goofy error

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

My teacher provided me `thebibliography` code and I copied it:

```
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems, serif]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}
    \underline{References}:
    
    \begin{thebibliography}{9}
        \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[book]        
        \bibitem \textit{Control Systems Engineering}, By Norman S. Nise, $7^{th}$ edition, John Wiley \& Sons, 2015. 
        \bibitem \textit{Modern Control Systems}, By Richard C. Dorf and Robert H. Bishop, $12^{th}$ edition, Pearson Education, Inc., 2011. 
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

However, I am getting this error message:

`Missing \endcsname inserted. ...\textit }{\hyperlink {beamerbib\textit }{1}}`

Output:
[image]

He used TexShop, I used TeXstudio. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro `\bibitem` expects an argument which serves as identifier, and can be used in `\cite`. So you need something like

```
    \begin{thebibliography}{9}
        \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[book]     
        \bibitem{A} \textit{Control Systems Engineering}, By Norman S. Nise, $7^{th}$ edition, John Wiley \& Sons, 2015. 
        \bibitem{B} \textit{Modern Control Systems}, By Richard C. Dorf and Robert H. Bishop, $12^{th}$ edition, Pearson Education, Inc., 2011. 
    \end{thebibliography}
```

Completed to an MWE this could look like

```
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems, serif]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{References}

    \begin{thebibliography}{9}
        \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[book]     
        \bibitem{A} \textit{Control Systems Engineering}, By Norman S. Nise, $7^{th}$ edition, John Wiley \& Sons, 2015. 
        \bibitem{B} \textit{Modern Control Systems}, By Richard C. Dorf and Robert H. Bishop, $12^{th}$ edition, Pearson Education, Inc., 2011. 
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It’s been a while since I have listed references on LaTeX (not on Beamer, though). Thank you for helping out!

Comment: @Superman You are welcome!